# grunt build and grunt serve

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

When running grunt build and grunt serve the following warning is coming :

```
Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. 
Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

grunt version:

```
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5
```

Operating System:

```
Windows 7
```

How to resolve this warning ? Is Ruby and Compass are required or without these I can proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your Gruntfile, probably you have to install ruby and compass to execute your tasks.

To install ruby in Windows you need to download the installer in [RubyInstaller for Windows](http://rubyinstaller.org/). Do not forget to open the installer as a administrator.

Then, to install compass you need sass and compass. Try it:

```
gem install sass
gem install compass
```

It should be fix your problem.

Comment: Installed Ruby and added to path also. How to run gem install sass and gem install compass ? Btw For me grunt build --force and grunt serve --force is working . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the follwing packages with NPM

```
 npm install grunt-contrib-sass ruby grunt-sass sass -g
```

If this doesn't work try installing Ruby on your environment.